# memory allocation in custom initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, profiler

Ran allocation profiler on my code. Found following problem on the inserted code. Could someone please point me what is wrong in the code. Added the picture so as too show the color coding.
[image]

Code for initializing the point is as below:

```
@autoreleasepool {

if(!coordString){
    return nil;
}
if([coordString length]<3){
    return nil;
}

__weak NSArray* coords=[coordString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    if(nil != coords && ([coords count]==2)){
    self = [super init];
    if(nil != self){
        self.coordX=  [[coords objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
        self.coordY = [[coords objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];

        return self;
    }else {
        return nil;
    }

    }else{

        return nil;
    }
}
```

Please suggest where the problem might be.
Allocation snapshot indicates the persistance memory.
[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense.  The screenshot shows different code, and what you posted looks like a messed up `init` method combined with some kind of getter.

Comment: Avi, if you go through the comment, the screenshot is initialization of plane object that uses code initialization of another point object, where profiler highlights in red. For reference I added the code that is referenced by that line. So you probably misunderstood the question.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the clarification.  What exactly is the problem?  Are you seeing a memory leak somewhere?  As an aside, you probably shouldn't have an `@autorelease` block in an initializer.

Comment: I don't find any memory leaks in the profiler in my code however the memory is showing increasing on every operation cycle I take on my application. So this means the persistance memory is being left behind. One of the function I picked up is in the screenshot I shared. I can take @autoreleasepool from my code snippet as I am not doing any further allocation but I left it in so as to make sure Array coords get released. IMHO there is no problem keeping it here.

Comment: The view you posted there is lifetime allocations, not current allocations.  It's expected to go up.

Comment: Added another pic above, about the allocation statistics.

Comment: I am not seeing a leak, but a snapshot without any other context is not going to show anything.  There's no way to tell you where in your app you're holding on to the 237 instances that are still live in the 2nd screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98122/discussion-between-yoku-and-avi).

Answer (score 0):

- There is no straight and clear solution one should expect on the memory related issues such as raised by my question above as there is no clear error is committed in the code. Leaks not picking anything specific. Hence @Avi above gave me a hint that the "Persistent" indicates the abandoned allocations. So his comment above gave me a direction that I need to look into the problems elsewhere.
- Someone who hasn't watched, should spend time understanding handling of memory issues using Instrument on the link https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-242/
- More important is to create the "dealloc" function for you such classes and create deallocation code for your code and set the pointers to nil. In my case above I made sure to do that using following code:

  -(void) dealloc{
  if(nil != self.arrVertices && [self isKindOfClass:[SPCPlane2D class]]){
      [self.arrVertices removeAllObjects];
   }
   self.arrVertices=nil;
  }

With few hours of digging further I have got the instrument showing as below

[image]